# Protocol vs Subclassing

Tags: objective-c, oop, protocols, subclassing

I have found that we can create model classes in Objective-C using following methods.

1. Create a protocol with some properties and methods. Implementing this protocol in any of the classes provide us an inheritance feature of OOP concept.
2. Create a NSObject class with interface and implementation. Add properties and method declarations to that class. SubClassing of this class also provide us an inheritance feature of OOP concept.

First of all I have to know that, these two methods will work as it stated.
If it will work what is difference between them, pros and cons.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are no pros and cons, `protocols` and `NSObject` subclasses are used for different purposes.

Comment: @Adam Could you please share at what instance we can use protocols and NSObject. I need to know the special cases for each usage.

Comment: Protocols - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1